# How to initialize a static std::unordered_map of a type trait?

Tags: c++, static-members, template-specialization, unordered-map, type-traits

Given the following type trait, how can I initialize `Fields` with some `std::pair`s?

```
template <>
struct ManagerDataTrait<Person>
{
    static const std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> Fields;
    // ...
};
```

I tried using a lambda but Visual Studio says that `Fields` is not an entity that can be explicitly specialized.

```
template <>
const std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> ManagerDataTrait<Person>::Fields = []{
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> fields;
    fields.insert(std::make_pair("height", "FLOAT"));
    fields.insert(std::make_pair("mass", "FLOAT"));
    return fields;
};
```

If there is no way to use static members like this in traits, which alternatives do I have to store the information in a trait? (`Fields` holds a SQL database structure.)

Update: The member might be also `const` but that shouldn't be the point.

Comment: For your lambda to work something would need to actually _run_ the lambda, but you haven't tried to do that (you've just tried to construct the hash map from the lambda, which isn't valid, but certainly doesn't run the lambda.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Kerrek SB's answer would be the right answer in general:

```
const std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> ManagerDataTrait<Person>::Fields{
  { "blah", "blah" }
  // ...
};
```

(N.B. no `template<>` because you're defining a member of a specialization, not a specialization)

But that isn't supported by Visual C++, so the other alternative is to initialize the map with a function call, and return a map with the desired contents from the function:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string>
getFields()
{
  std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> fields;
  fields["blah"] = "blah";
  // ...
  return fields;
}

const std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> ManagerDataTrait<Person>::Fields = getFields();
```

A lambda is just syntactic sugar for doing the same thing, and I'm not sure it's clearer to use a lambda because the syntax is a bit uglier.

Answer (score 28):

You realize you can initialize maps from braced lists?

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> m { { "a", "bc" }
                                               , { "b", "xy" }
//                                               ...
                                               };
```

Comment: The solution was to get rid of the `template <>`, which you pointed out in a now deleted comment. Could you please add this to your answer? I'll mark it as accepted then.

Comment: I made (and deleted) such a comment, is that the one you mean?

Comment: @JonathanWakely You are right, I meant your comment. I mixed that up.

Answer (score 2):

Visual C++ now supports static initialization from braced lists, so you could do something like this:

```
const std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> ManagerDataTrait<Person>::Fields{ { "abc", "xyz" }, { "cde", "zyx" } ...};
```